# Firefox Chrome line-height differences

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

I've been grappling with a Firefox/Chrome line-height issue in a Joomla article where the elements, "intro_content", require line-height = 2em  and line-height = 1em in Firefox and Chrome respectively in order to display as required. I've tried using normalize.css and Meyer's reset without success. So I tried Modernizr (which I'm using elsewhere on the site anyhow).  This is the js:

```
      var selectEl =  jQuery("p.intro_content"),
      browserFF = Modernizr.addTest('firefox', function (){
          return !!navigator.userAgent.match(/firefox/i).data();
        });
      if(browserFF) {
        selectEl.css("line-height", "2");
      }else{
         selectEl.css("line-height", "1");
      }
       alert(browserFF);
```

The alert returns "object Object". However, the display difference remains. . But if val() or data() are appended to the returning expression, so

```
      !!navigator.userAgent.match(/firefox/i).val();      // or  data()
```

the alert is not displayed. I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Can you add the code that will certainly display this behaviour and put it into a snippet for us to help reproduce the issue?

Comment: _“The alert returns "object Object"”_ – then log it to console, instead of alerting it, so that you can see what it actually contains. And from looking at the docs I wonder, aren’t you supposed to just use `Modernizr.firefox` now to see what result your test yielded? Btw., that such a hugely different line-height is “required” in different browsers might be an issue with _your_ CSS, rather than a bug/misinterpretation/difference of opinion in browsers … I would investigate that properly first, before trying to “fix” the issue with JS.

Comment: @CBroe  your suggestion to use Modernizr.firefox was spot on. Changing the if condition to "browserFF.firefox" did the trick. I also ran the css file thru a validator -  many parsing errors  which I need to check out.

Answer (score 0):

*[My earlier comment]* From looking at the docs I wonder, aren’t you supposed to just use `Modernizr.firefox` now to see what result your test yielded?

> your suggestion to use Modernizr.firefox was spot on. Changing the if condition to "browserFF.firefox" did the trick

I don’t think you need the `browserFF` variable here at all. You don’t need to “catch” the return value of `Modernizr.addTest`, because that will just be the global `Modernizr` object itself again.

So simply using

```
if(Modernizr.firefox) { …
```

should work just fine.